# Nemo won't stop crashing, trying to fix it actually broke Firefox and other things

Tags: linux, firefox, linux-mint, glibc, python3

I'm using LMDE Betsy, and nemo has been crashing all the time lately. The windows usually last a few seconds, and the Desktop icons keep disappearing as well.

I've tried to fix it in several ways found in forums, including updating the file `nemo-autostart.desktop` with `NoDisplay=true`, and installing these libraries:

```
apt-get install eject librsvg2-common gvfs-backends nemo-fileroller gir1.2-nemo-3.0 \
    libnemo-extension1 nemo-data nemo-emblems nemo-folder-color-switcher \
    nemo-image-converter nemo-share python-nemo
```

Now Firefox keeps crashing upon starting. Safe mode crashes as well, with these messages:

```
rioualen@dell3b31852 /opt/firefox $ firefox -safe-mode

(firefox-esr:2081): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed
ExceptionHandler::GenerateDump cloned child 2133
ExceptionHandler::SendContinueSignalToChild sent continue signal to child
ExceptionHandler::WaitForContinueSignal waiting for continue signal...
```

I've tried reinstalling glibc libraries with no success.

I've noticed other programs have stopped working properly: I had to reinstall `python3` libraries with `pip3` although I had them already. Inkscape and Shutter also disappeared. Gedit plugins have disappeared, and I can't seem to install them back:

```
rioualen@dell3b31852 ~/ChIP-seq_GSE20870 $ sudo apt-get install gedit-plugins
[...]
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gedit-plugins : Depends: gedit (>= 2.25.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
rioualen@dell3b31852 ~/ChIP-seq_GSE20870 $ gedit -V
gedit - Version 3.14.0
```

And Nemo still doesnt work properly!

Is there some kind of broken path? Thank you so much.

System info:

```
rioualen@dell3b31852 /opt/firefox $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    LMDE 2 Betsy
Release:    2
Codename:   betsy

rioualen@dell3b31852 /opt/firefox $ uname -a 
Linux dell3b31852 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u5 (2015-10-09) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```